# SOAP + PHP(Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, soap

Кто нибудь может подсказать логику SOAP, нужно интегрировать в сайт платежку онлайн, скинули wsdl файл от процессинга, я его загрузил в soapui, увидел все методы, но до сих пор нет понимания где создавать запрос и как получать ответы, буду признателен за помощь

Answer (score 4):

Приведу пример на [php soap](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.soap.php)

```
$soap = new \SoapClient($host, [
                'login' => $name,
                'password' => $password,              
                'exceptions' => true,
                'keep_alive' => false,
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,                    
                'trace' => true,
            ]);
```

Дальше вызываете метод который нужен (который описан в wsdl):

```
$result = $soap->GetMyMethod();
```